# Writing EXIF coordinates to images based on common field?

Tags: geocoding, exif

we did a photo survey with a GPS equipped camera (1800 images), then to improve accuracy we did a survey with a total station and renamed images with points labels.
Now I need to write the new coordinates into the images EXIF data (re-geocode images), using the image name as the matching field. The only method I found is based on time matching of a GPS track but this is not the case.

Comment: in what format are the new coordinates?  I'd consider looping over the image names, looking up the coordinates for the matching name, and then modifying the files with exiftool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion. Finally I did exactly what I was looking for using the software [PhotoMapper Desktop](http://www.alta4.com/en/photo-documentation/gps-based-photo-documentation/software-solutions/photomapper-desktop.html).